# Castle Windsor injecting controller with two instances of same interface

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor

I have my controller like this

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    private IEntityRepository accountsRepo;
    private IEntityRepository dataRepo;

    public MyController(IEntityRepository accs, IEntityRepository data)
    {
        accountsRepo = accs;
        dataRepo = data;
    }
.....
}
```

And I installed container this way:

```
public class RepositoriesInstaller : IWindsorInstaller
{
    public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
    {
        container.Register(
            Component.For<IEntityRepository>()
                .ImplementedBy<AccountsRepository>()
                .Named("accs")
                .LifestyleTransient(),
            Component.For<IEntityRepository>()
                .ImplementedBy<DataRepository>()
                .Named("data")
                .LifestyleTransient());

    }
}
```

Also I have facilities setted up:

```
public class PersistenceFacility : AbstractFacility
{
    protected override void Init()
    {
        Kernel.Register(
            Component.For<DbContext>()
                .ImplementedBy<AccountsContext>()
                .LifestylePerWebRequest(),
            Component.For<DbContext>()
                .ImplementedBy<DataContext>()
                .LifestylePerWebRequest());
    }
}
```

}

...and installed:

```
public class PersistenceInstaller : IWindsorInstaller
{
    public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
    {
        container.AddFacility<PersistenceFacility>();
    }
}
```

So when I'm using my controller both parameters are injected with AccountsRepository instance (which was registered first). Of course I wanna see "data" being DataRepository respectively. Please, explain me proper way to deal with this kind of injection.

**EDIT**

As @roman suggested I have implemented generic repositories:

```
public interface IRepository : IDisposable
{
    void SaveChanges();

    void ExecuteProcedure(String procedureCommand, params SqlParameter[] sqlParams);
}

public interface IEntityRepository<T> : IRepository
{
    T Context { get; set; }
    DbSet<TEntity> Set<TEntity>() where TEntity : class;
}

public class AccountsRepository : IEntityRepository<AccountsContext>
{
    public AccountsContext Context { get; set; }

    public AccountsRepository(AccountsContext c)
    {
        Context = c;
    }

    public DbSet<TEntity> Set<TEntity>() where TEntity : class
    {
        return Context.Set<TEntity>();
    }

    public virtual void ExecuteProcedure(String procedureCommand, params SqlParameter[] sqlParams)
    {
        Context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(procedureCommand, sqlParams);
    }

    public virtual void SaveChanges()
    {
        Context.SaveChanges();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (Context != null)
            Context.Dispose();
    }
}
```

DataRepository looks the same way, my be at some point I will decide to have just one concrete class EntityRepository, but it not relevant to exceptions I receiving.
So after cosmetic interfaces changes my contreller become:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private IEntityRepository<AccountsContext> accountsRepo;
    private IEntityRepository<DataContext> dataRepo;

    public HomeController(IEntityRepository<AccountsContext> accs, IEntityRepository<DataContext> data)
    {
        accountsRepo = accs;
        dataRepo = data;
    }
    ....
}
```

Also I have changed installer code:

```
        container.Register(
            Component.For<IEntityRepository<AccountsContext>>()
                .ImplementedBy<AccountsRepository>()
                .LifestyleTransient(),
            Component.For<IEntityRepository<DataContext>>()
                .ImplementedBy<DataRepository>()
                .LifestyleTransient());
```

And now during controller resolving proccess

```
        return (IController) kernel.Resolve(controllerType);
```

I catching

Can't create component 'MyMVCProj.DAL.AccountsRepository' as it has dependencies to be satisfied.

```
'MyMVCProj.DAL.AccountsRepository' is waiting for the following dependencies:
- Service 'MyMVCProj.DAL.AccountsContext' which was not registered.

Castle.MicroKernel.Handlers.HandlerException: Can't create component     'MyMVCProj.DAL.AccountsRepository' as it has dependencies to be satisfied.

'MyMVCProj.DAL.AccountsRepository' is waiting for the following dependencies:
- Service 'MyMVCProj.DAL.AccountsContext' which was not registered.
```

But I have installed AccountsContext in facility logic.

**EDIT++**
According to @Roman suggestion I have tweaked my facility this way:

```
public class PersistenceFacility : AbstractFacility
{
    protected override void Init()
    {
        Kernel.Register(
            Component.For<DbContext>()
                .ImplementedBy<AccountsContext>()
                .Named("accctx")
                .LifestylePerWebRequest(),
            Component.For<DbContext>()
                .ImplementedBy<DataContext>()
                .Named("datactx")
                .LifestylePerWebRequest());
    }
}
```

and also repositories installler:

```
public class RepositoriesInstaller : IWindsorInstaller
{
    public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
    {
        container.Register(
            Component.For<IEntityRepository<AccountsContext>>()
                .ImplementedBy<AccountsRepository>()
                .Named("accs‌​")
                .LifestyleTransient()
                .DependsOn(Dependency.OnComponent(typeof (DbContext), "accctx")),
            Component.For<IEntityRepository<DataContext>>()
                .ImplementedBy<DataRepository>()
                .Named("data")
                .LifestyleTransient()
                .DependsOn(Dependency.OnComponent(typeof (DbContext), "datactx")));
    }
}
```

This is the exception I get now:

```
Can't create component 'accs‌​' as it has dependencies to be satisfied.
'accs‌​' is waiting for the following dependencies:
- Service 'MyMVCProj.DAL.AccountsContext' which was not registered.
```

But trying to solve this brute forcing the code I ended with working solution, just installing concrete implementations of DBContext:

```
public class PersistenceFacility : AbstractFacility
{
    protected override void Init()
    {
        Kernel.Register(
            Component.For<AccountsContext>().LifestylePerWebRequest(),
            Component.For<DataContext>().LifestylePerWebRequest());
    }
}
```

And kernel's components now are:

```
    AccountsContext PerWebRequest   
    AccountsRepository / IEntityRepository<AccountsContext> Transient
    DataContext PerWebRequest   
    DataRepository / IEntityRepository<DataContext> Transient
```

And before they were:

```
    AccountsContext / DbContext PerWebRequest   
    AccountsRepository / IEntityRepository<AccountsContext> Transient
    DataContext / DbContext PerWebRequest   
    DataRepository / IEntityRepository<DataContext> Transient
```

So the new questions are:

Have I did all stuff idiomatically?
Why this behaviour - there already was AccountContext with little mention of it dependencies.

Comment: Well, seems like you're missing AccountContext in the container. You do register it as DbContext, but your IEntityRepository<Account> expects a concrete DbContext of type AccountContext. try giving the DBContext registration of concrete type AccountContext a name, and then use the castle Dependency fluent api to register the entity repository with a name, for example:  Component.For<IEntityRepository().ImplementedBy<AccountsRepository().Named("accs").LifestyleTransient().DependsOn(Dependency.OnComponent(typeof(DbContext), "AccountContext")

Comment: try changing the AccountsRepository constructor to demand DbContext, instead of AccountsContext

Answer (score 1):

The fact that you expect two instances of same interface, yet you require different behavior for them (by injecting them to two different parameters), implies - in my opinion - that they shouldn't be the same interface, because they have different roles, or responsibilities. It would make sense to me more, if IEntityRepository was a generic class and then you would require in MyController two different generic interface types:

```
public class MyController(IEntityRepository<Account> acc, IEntityRepository<Data> data)
```

Nevertheless, If you still want to do that kind of thing, I suggest you use a CollectionResolver that will allow MyController class to get an IEnumerable. That way you'll get both instances, but it'll be up to you to select the appropriate one to use depending on your needs, which I'll stress again, I think is the wrong approach for this.

To use CollectionResolver you need to register it with the Windsor container like this:

```
var container = new WindsorContainer();
container.Kernel.Resolver.AddSubResolver(new CollectionResolver(container.Kernel));
```

And then, MyController will look like this:

```
 public class MyController(IEnumerable<IEntityRepository> repositories)
 {
    accountsRepo = repositories.Where(...);
    dataRepo = repositories.Where(...);
 }
```

Comment: When I did implement repositories as generics exception was introduced: 'MyMVCProj.DAL.AccountsRepository' is waiting for the following dependencies:
- Service 'MyMVCProj.DAL.AccountsContext' which was not registered. The only changes I did, except tweaking repo's code was dependencies registration.:                    Component.For<IEntityRepository<AccountsContext>>()
                    .ImplementedBy<AccountsRepository>()
                    .LifestyleTransient() ...);

Comment: Seems like you have some other issue going on there that has nothing to do with the discussed subject. Post your entire code so the community will be able to help you fully.

Comment: @SergeyPrytkov, How are you going to use them. It looks like having  a list of `IEntityRepository` is the best solution.

Comment: Seems I got working solution, also with new questions.

Comment: What new questions do you have?

Comment: The point of .. interfaces .. is to allow different implementations and/or components of such. Imagine there is an "ILogger" one for errors, one for warnings, how to wire this up?